# ImportError: No module named extern;

Tags: python, linux, setuptools

I'm trying to install fuel and blocks with

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mila-udem/blocks.git@v0.0.1                        
pip install git+git://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git@v0.0.1
```

(I was using the root account)
Then I encountered the problem

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git@v0.0.1                       
Downloading/unpacking git+git://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git@v0.0.1   
Cloning git://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git to /tmp/pip-PnqUs3-build
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-PnqUs3-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+git://github.com/mila-udem/fuel.git                                          
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                               
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>                                         
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>                                                                     
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in  <module>                                                                
    ImportError: No module named extern                                            
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 3, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named extern

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

I have tried to reinstall/update setuptools and still can't get it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

download: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/extern/0.1.0

install: `tar zxf extern-0.1.0.tar.gz && python setup.py install`

Comment: Presumably `pip install -U extern` would also work, if this does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on CentOS7 and got it resolved by doing:

`pip install -U extern`
You can cross check in your active python version, if you can import the module extern. If that works, then rebuild your `easy_install` from the downloaded `ez_setup.py`. e.g. `/opt/bin/python ez_setup.py`

This will include the `extern` module into the `easy_install` routine and the error doesn't show up anymore.

Running then `/opt/bin/easy_install <your.egg>` should do the job. Note: if you have more than one python version, use fully qualified names or softlinks you created in `/usr/bin/`